# Install Ubuntu 11.04 on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have been using Ubuntu 10.04 since more than 6 months, mainly for development purposes (Android, LAMP).

I got Ubuntu 11.04 last night and quite liked it.
I was just wondering if I can directly upgrade my 10.04 to 11.04 using the CD that I have got.
Should I go for a 10.10 upgrade first then move to 11.04?
My system is already 100% updated.

I also read on some places that the Unity and the new unified bar requires some applications (such as Eclipse IDE) to be configured specifically to be used with it.
Is it true?

Comment: Insert the CD. There should be an option to update to 11.04. I think it's possible to directly upgrade to 11.04, because a distro upgrade "just" updates some PPAs :)

Comment: Have you tried doing this?

Comment: It is (arguably) safer for your system to just do a clean install. Just my two cents.

Comment: @zookalicios That's the last option, but that will perhaps need installation of all the software that I have, all over again. plus will also wash out my HDD I guess. (I am not a Linux installation pro)

Comment: You can..however you should really be doing this 10.04 to 10.10 to 11.04

Comment: Ughh.. that's going to be painful to go to 10.10 first and then to 11.04 :-(

Comment: @Uri Herrera No that will not give any benefit . the 11.04 upgrade system is really awesome and works quite well .

Comment: not really , i uprgaded and it broke everything, i had to reinstall 10.10 or mint 10 to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly upgrade from 10.04 to 11.04 ( p.s. I upgraded from 10.04 to 11.04 yesterday) .

You have to Insert the cd and boot from it then click install ubuntu then you will get 3 options : remove  10.04 LTS and install 11.04 , Upgrade 10.04 LTS to 11.04, Install alongside.
Select the 2 one and you are good to go.

Comment: This one is quite detailed. thanks man. I'll give it a try, and I already feel that it will work. but I also feel that some programs might fail to work at all and will need some tweaking or config :P

Answer (score 0):

You can, I guess, because on 10.10 it gave me the option to do so. Or you can download the alternate installation disc.

Comment: You mean I can just put the 11.04 CD and update?

Comment: Yes, you can do so